# Comodo SSL (Essential SSL) Cert not Trusted

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have had several hundred visitors and there have been two or three that have reported to get the "This website is insecure" warnings. The latest reported the same result in both the latest version of Firefox (57) and IE. I've tested on several browsers and OS's; including the same config of (win7 and FF57) the last report I have and didn't see issue. The only thing I can figure is the user's computer perhaps has malware that has overwritten their root certs. Does that make sense? Any other possibilities here?

Comment: Have you checked at something like SSL Labs? https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: Awesome tool, thanks. I got a 'B' for (The server's certificate chain is incomplete). I suppose that's something I can look into. Is it possible that his browsers could have an elevated security level? Many of my visitors are at academic institutions and I believe is the case for the one I'm in touch with now.

Comment: If your certificate chain is incomplete, that's your problem. Some devices have enough in their root certificate store to trust the certificate, others don't. I suspect you're missing an 'intermediate certificate' to link your certificate to the root authority. I'd reach out to your certificate authority (the people who signed and issued your valid certificate) and see if they have any recommendations about that.

Comment: I'm now an A- so hopefully that will pass all the browsers. This was all very helpful. This site made it really easy to get my cert right. https://certificatechain.io.